# How to increase space between chart and legend? (googlecharts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, chart.js, chartkick

I am using chartkick gem with googlecharts. I need to add space between chart and legend text.

```
<%= pie_chart [["Cash", @currentHoldings['priceChangePercent']], ["Equity", @currentHoldings['equityPercentage']], ["ManagedFunds", @currentHoldings['managedFundsPercentage']]], library: {pieSliceText:'percentage'},donut:true, legend: 'top',height: "200px", colors: ["#1e88e5","#8e24aa","#00acc1"] %>
```

how to add margin for legend?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to do it by using and modifying chartkick.js rather than using the gem. Other option is to supress the legend and build your own

Comment: thanks for youe suggestion. i will add custom legend with my own

Comment: Prudent course of action. Kindly accept the answer in case someone else has the same issue.